# What's the equivalent of vbroadcastsd for xmm registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, avx

There doesn't seem to be a version of `vbroadcastsd` which takes a 64-bit memory source operand with `xmm` destination registers, which is kind of weird since the `ymm` and `zmm` versions exist.

So I guess there is some existing instruction that covers this purpose?

Comment: Just look at the code generated by your compiler for `__m128d f(double*x){return _mm_set1_pd(*x);}` when you enable various instruction sets?

Comment: @MarcGlisse - good call! It [emits `vmovddup`](https://godbolt.org/z/Ahp0e4) or `movddup` or something worse if you just use base SSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SSE3 `movddup xmm, xmm/m64`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVDDUP.html) is a 64->128 broadcast.

Interestingly, the AVX1 256-bit version (`vmovddup ymm, ymm/m256`) does two separate in-lane broadcasts, and has a 256-bit memory source.  But with a memory source, it still runs purely on a load port on Intel CPUs, like broadcast-loads.

As you say, [`vbroadcastsd ymm, m64`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VBROADCAST.html) is AVX1, `vbroadcastsd ymm, xmm` is AVX2, and there is no `vbroadcastsd` with an XMM destination.

---

If it wasn't for the memory-source-only nature of AVX1 broadcasts, Intel might have just made the 256-bit version of `movddup` *be* `vbroadcastsd`.  i.e. 128-bit vmovddup and vbroadcastsd could have been aliases for the same opcode.

But splitting them up let Intel make a m64 -> ymm broadcast for AVX1, while still providing `vmovddup xmm, xmm/m64` with the source allowed to be a register.  I don't know why the provided a 256-bit in-lane-broadcast version.  Maybe that's actually useful sometimes, or they could do it cheaply.

If `vbroadcastsd` is encoded with `VEX.L= 0` (implying 128-bit vector width), the manual explicitly says it will #UD.  So there isn't an undocumented 128-bit version.